# If a graph G has chromatic number 3, then G contains a subgraph isomorphic to $K_3$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is there a theorem that states if a graph has $\chi(G) = n$ then it also contains a subgraph isomorphic to $K_n$?

Comment: You are trying to compare the chromatic number to the so called clique number. There is a whole literature about this problem. Google should provide relevant information.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the cycle on $5$ vertices.

Comment: Yes, $\chi(G)=3$ here but no $K_3$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simply NO, since there are triangle-free graphs with arbitrarily high chromatic number, in virtue of the following lemma:

If $G$ is a triangle-free graph with chromatic number $n$, its [Mycelskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian) $M(G)$ is a triangle free graph with chromatic number $n+1$.